# Django and BeautifulSoup - Run views.py on each pageload?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I am completely new to Django, so sorry for the maybe very basic question, but I couldn't come up with an asnwer yet. I've installed Django on Ubuntu and Virtualenv. I also installed BeautifulSoup and Requests. So I started an app called scrape and imported Requests and BeautifulSoup in my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.krone.at")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

headings = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"item"})
headings = headings[0: 10]

news = []

for items in headings:
    news.append(items.text.strip())


def scrape_view(request):

    return render(request, 'scrape.html', {'news': news})
```

my template (scrape.html) looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h2>Krone (Newsticker)</h2>

{% for item in news %}

<span class="krone headline">{{ forloop.counter }} - {{ item }}</span><br />

{% endfor %}    

{% endblock content %}
```

So basically, this works just fine. I scrape with Requests and BeautifulSoup the first 10 headlines of an Austrian newspaper. Then I pass it to the template and run a for loop which gives me all the headlines. BUT, when I refresh the page, I'll always get the same headlines, even if they have been changed already on the website I am scraping from. When I then kill the Server and run the server again, I get the new headlines.

So, my question would be how to get it working, that my BeautifulSoup code gets executed on every pageload. So that when I integrate a button to refresh the page, all headlines get updated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Put your scrape code inside your view method, so that on every refresh it scrapes new data.

Comment: Oh boy, I am just such a honk. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jeet commented, moving the BS logic into the view will run your scraper everytime your view is called. Logic outside a function in `views.py` is only run on server reboot.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrape_view(request):

    r = requests.get("https://www.krone.at")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    headings = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"item"})
    headings = headings[0: 10]

    news = []

    for items in headings:
        news.append(items.text.strip())

    return render(request, 'scrape.html', {'news': news})
```

P.S. Since you are doing web scraping, I'd consider doing some rate limiting so that your app isn't spamming `https://www.krone.at` if the view suddenly gets 100 requests / second. However, it really depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! At the moment, I am just interested in learning Django and scraping with Python and BeautifulSoup. So this is basically a small learning inviroment I run locally on a Raspberry Pi. Only usecase so far is giving me back the first 10 headlines of the newspapers I read every day. But yes, for a production site, this would sure need rate limiting :)